# Having both long term and short term slots on Rococo

Tags: rococo, slot

Is it possible to have both a long term slot and also a short term slot on the Rococo test relay chain?  We currently have a long term slot but would like the possibility of having a short term slot to validate another runtime version.

Comment: I think this should be an issue in https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues.